# Azure DevOps PS REST API : No api-version was supplied for the \"PUT\" request. The version must be supplied either as part of the Accept header

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-rest-api

I am trying to run below script to create and add data in Azure DevOps wiki page:

```
$JSONBody= @{
   "Content"="PR# $PullRequestId : $PullRequestTitle `n `n WorkItem# $workItemId : $taskTitle `n `n Iteration: $taskIterationPath `n `n Tags: $taskTags `n `n Description: `n `n $taskDescription" 
}

$wikiuri="https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/{proj_name}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wiki-proj-name}.wiki/pages?path=Release Notes/$todayDate/PR-$PullRequestId-$PullRequestTitle-$(RELEASE.ATTEMPTNUMBER)&api-version=5.0"

$Response=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $wikiuri `
                            -Method PUT `
                            -Body ($JSONBody|ConvertTo-Json) `
                            -ContentType "application/json" `
                            -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $Base64AuthInfo)}
```

Above script used to work just fine. But from last week or so, it started throwing below error:

> Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":No
> api-version was supplied for the "PUT" request.  The version must be
> supplied either as part of the Accept header (e.g. "application/json;
> api-version=1.0") or as a  query parameter (e.g.
> "?api-version=1.0").
> "typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssVersionNotSpecifiedException,
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi","typeKey":"VssVersionNotSpecifiedException","errorCode":0

Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Aniket Karajgikar; the error message is quite clear about the problem and how to fix it: "No api-version was supplied for the "PUT" request. The version must be supplied either as part of the Accept header (e.g. "application/json; api-version=1.0") or as a query parameter (e.g. "?api-version=1.0")." . Have you not tried following that instruction?

Comment: In my above script, -Uri $wikiuri already contains '&api-version=5.0'

Answer (score 1):

The error happens on your `$wikiuri` string. Use `+` to combine `&api-version=5.0`. Sample as below:

```
$wikiuri="https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/{proj_name}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wiki-proj-name}.wiki/pages?path=Release Notes/$todayDate/PR-$PullRequestId-$PullRequestTitle-$(RELEASE.ATTEMPTNUMBER)" + "&api-version=5.0"
```

Suggest to `Write-Host $wikiuri` to output the value for a check, make sure it has correct value with `&api-version=5.0` ending and no special characters inside, since you are using variable here, eg: PullRequestTitle.

Comment: Thanks for good suggestion. Issue was with $PullRequestTitle. It contained '#' char in it, which is not supported by azure devops wiki as a Title of page.

Comment: Glad to know it's helpful! Could you please mark it as answer so it can help other who encounter the same problem? Thanks.